# Best way to hash sets of three integers

Tags: java, optimization, data-structures, hashmap, tuples

I'm trying to write a program that quickly finds all words that match a string with wildcards and known letters. For example, L*G would return LOG, LAG, LEG. I'm looking for something that would give me very fast lookup, but I don't care about time it takes to create the tree in the first place.

My idea is a Hashmap of "Triples" mapping to an ArrayList of Strings: basically, a list of all Strings that match the criteria for a certain index, character at that index, and length.

But my issue now is generating a good hash function for these "Triples" such that every triplet is unique.

Here's my code for what I have right now.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class CWSolutionT {
HashMap<Triple, ArrayList<String>> tripleMap = new HashMap<Triple, ArrayList<String>>();

public CWSolutionT(List<String> allWords) {
    for (String word : allWords) {
        for (int letter = 0; letter < word.length(); letter++) {
            ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
            Triple key = new Triple(letter, word.charAt(letter),
                    word.length());
            if (tripleMap.get(key) == null) {
                tempList.add(word);
                tripleMap.put(key, tempList);
            } else {
                tempList = tripleMap.get(key);
                tempList.add(word);
                tripleMap.put(key, tempList);
            }
        }
    }
}

public List<String> solutions(String pattern, int maxRequired) {
    List<String> sol = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<List<String>> solList = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    int length = pattern.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (pattern.charAt(i) != '*') {
            Triple key = new Triple(i, pattern.charAt(i), pattern.length());
            solList.add(tripleMap.get(key));
        }
    }
    if (solList.size() == 0) {
        // implement later
    }

    if (solList.size() == 1)
        return solList.get(0);

    for (List<String> list : solList) {
        sol.retainAll(list);
    }
    return sol;
}

private class Triple {
    public final int index;
    public final char letter;
    public final int length;

    public Triple(int ind, char let, int len) {
        index = ind;
        letter = let;
        length = len;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null)
            return false;
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Triple)) {
            return false;
        }
        Triple comp = (Triple) o;
        if (this.hashCode() == comp.hashCode())
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "(" + index + ", " + letter + ", " + length + ")";
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (int) (.5 * (index + letter + length)
                * (index + letter + length + 1) + letter + length);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please build a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) to demonstrate the issue

Comment: You `hashCode` can't be used like this, see my answer.

Comment: If you're writing a word game, you should look up Directed Acyclic Word Graph.

Answer (score 4):

You have to overrride [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) as well in your `Tuple` class

Comment: since your tuple is dealing with to objects use their hashCodes and a cantor pairing to calculate a unique hashCode from those: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%5Fpairing%5Ffunction#Cantor_pairing_function

Comment: @Kai Huppmann: Cantor pairing stops working whenever an overflow occurs. Actually, for a limited domain there's no reason to try.

Comment: @maartinus Don't know what you mean. Sure with big original hash codes you'll get out of int-range, but the contract for hashCode() and equals() will still be fulfilled. What does 'for a limited domain there's no reason to try' mean? What's your alternative?

Answer (score 0):

HashMap requires an implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` and you haven't overridden either of them. Right now your map is basically only checking object identify (someOldObject == someNewObject).

It looks like you've attempted to implement an equals method but the signature is wrong, `Object#equals` takes an `Object` as a parameter and yours takes a `Tuple` so it is instead *overloaded*. Answers for this question have some tips for implementing equals and hashCode: [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's impossible to squeze two `int`s into a single one. Cantor pairing function works for an infinite domain, but transferring it to `int`s leads nowhere.

Your input is a triple `(int, char, int)`, which theoretically accounts for `2**32 * 2**16 * 2**32 = 2**80` possibilities, which obviously can't be injectively mapped onto a set containing `2**32` elements only.

With the help of some knowledge about the input values you can do better, but possibly not good enough. For example, you know that both `index` and `length` are non-negative, which makes your domain four times smaller... but that's nothing.

If you knew that both `index` and `length` are less than 256, you could do the mapping via

```
public int hashCode() {
    return index + 256 * length + 256 * 256 * letter;
}
```

This expression can be written more efficiently as

```
index + (length << 8) + (letter << 16)
```

but you can leave it to the JIT compiler.

It's well possible that you can't reduce the domain sufficiently and then I'd suggest to let it be. Just compare the fields... you could try to fit it in a long, but isn't it all [the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)?

Note that your

```
public int hashCode() {
    return (int) (.5 * (index + letter + length)
            * (index + letter + length + 1) + letter + length);
}
```

is too bad.... you're using *a pairing of three things*! The tuples `(0, 'A', 1)` and `(0, 'B', 0)` have the same `hashCode` and thus your `equals` return true. You're actually Cantor-pairing `index` and `letter + length` while you'd have to use two pairings.